# Перехват ссылок на файлы ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

У меня есть legacy приложение windows, которое обращается к сайту для загрузки картинок, по ссылкам такого вида [http://сдпп.рф/user_images/chat/5461fbe12552c.jpg](http://%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%BF.%D1%80%D1%84/user_images/chat/5461fbe12552c.jpg) . Этот сайт планируется выключить, т.к. мне нужен этот домен для будущей разработки сайта другой программы. Я собираюсь постепенно изучая ASP.NET написать новый сайт, но сейчас мне нужна заглушка которая обеспечит работу старых ссылок. Я написал такой код:

```
public class Users_imagesController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Chat()
    {
        NameValueCollection name_value_collection = Request.Params;
        return View();
    }
}
```

И ссылки вида [http://сдпп.рф/user_images/chat/5461fbe12552c](http://%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%BF.%D1%80%D1%84/user_images/chat/5461fbe12552c) стали попадать в этот метод, но стоит добавить к пути расширение файла (.jpg), сразу ошибка 404

Comment: видимо стоит обработчик который любое *.jpg обрабатывает как статические файлы. Такие обработчики можно прописывать и отписывать в файле конфигурации. `<system.webServer><handlers>`

Comment: Вот тут сказано как можно удалять существующие https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/handlers/

Comment: Вы можете определить свой обработчик для картинок, вот так https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/19.5.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете определить свой обработчик для картинок. Это пример обработчика.

```
public class UserInfoHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        /* Пример кода обработчика */            
        string result = "<p>Ваш IP: "+context.Request.UserHostAddress+"</p>";
        result+="<p>UserAgent: "+context.Request.UserAgent+"</p>";
        context.Response.Write(result);
    }
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

а вот так обработчик прописывается в конфиг файл.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<!--остальное содержимое-->
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="MyHttpHandler" path="/handler/" verb="GET" type="LifeCycleApp.Handlers.UserInfoHandler"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

В вашем случае в path надо будет указать `"*.jpg"`

Источник - https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/19.5.php

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/219593)

Comment: Комментарий-ссылка я ещё понимаю, но ответ ссылка - это перебор

Comment: @0xdb Сейчас поправлю.

Comment: @tym32167 я поправил, если вы мне поставили голос вниз, прошу пересмотреть.

Comment: Свсем другое дело, теперь плюс :)

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо!

Comment: Так хорошо (+). Странно, что вы с вашей  дастаточно высокой репутацией допустили такой ляп.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин В целом мне это помогло, единственное что не хватало этой строчки в файле RouteConfig.cs: ```routes.IgnoreRoute("users_images/{*path}");```